# By which interaction will proton decay?

Tags: particle-physics, beyond-the-standard-model, protons, grand-unification, proton-decay

I learned that proton takes at least $10^{34}$ years to [decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay). If it will decay one day, will it decay via weak interaction or some other interaction?

Comment: I think my answer here covers the question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282655/